# Expanding wrong rolled div

Tags: jquery, css

I've got list of divs - 2 divs in a row.
These divs are rolled and have hidden content. To expand div, there is an arrow for that.
Now, when I want to expand 1 div, the second in the same line is expanding too.
It's something like:

[scr1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QLe1.png)

After expand the left one:

[scr2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp3g1.png)

How set the second div to stay rolled, even if the other div in the same line is expanding?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.infoTestDiv').hide();

  $(".testBtnExpand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.infoTestDiv').slideDown(200);

    return false;
  });

  $(".testBtnRoll").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.infoTestDiv').slideUp(200);

    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.testDiv {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 testDiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <btn class="btn testBtnExpand">Click to expand</btn>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <btn class="btn testBtnRoll">Click to roll up</btn>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoTestDiv">
      <h4>Hello</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 testDiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <btn class="btn testBtnExpand">Click to expand</btn>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <btn class="btn testBtnRoll">Click to roll up</btn>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="infoTestDiv">
      <h4>Hello</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example of my problem on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/paprikano/9eaqg5jt/2/

Comment: If I were you, I will give every `.testInfoDiv` an ID, so that you can control the DIV easily.

Comment: @Raptor result is the same. The second div in a line should be positioned well or something like this I think

Comment: You can do this alignment with `flexbox` ... can you post some example HTML with the boxes? Not the template on how it's built but the final html

Comment: @cloned example on JSFiddle added to a post